# How to suppress a compiler warning in C# without using #pragma?

Tags: c#, .net, suppress-warnings

I need to suppress a specfic compiler warning in C#. Now I can do it like this:

```
#pragma warning disable 0649

private string _field;

#pragma warning restore 0649
```

Is there a way to do it like the following?

```
[SuppressCompilerWarning("0649")]
private string _field;
```

Because I only need to suppress warnings for this field, not a code block.

Note: I want to suppress the **compiler warning**, not the Code-Analysis warning.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doesn't:

```
private string _field = null;
```

remove the warning as well?

Answer (score 2):

No. You can do it project wide via a build flag, but otherwise a field is just another (small) block.

Of course, you could assign it a value somewhere... that'll make it happy ;-p (I'm assuming it is actually assigned a value via reflection or something?)

Comment: You're right. It will be assiged by a DI framework, and that field should not be visible to the outside world.

Comment: The problem is, using a #pragma pair is really boring.

Comment: @Dylan - then give the code a value somewhere. Frankly huge chunks of most code might be considered "boring" - but they are critical.